# How do i create a mock object that uses an array of traits?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am currently on PHPUnit v5.7.27

I would like to create a mock object that uses an array of traits. How would I go about this? I only see `getMockForTrait` as a way to create a mock object using a single trait. My issue is that the trait requires the existence of another trait at the class level.

Update: More context to the issue

Given:

```
trait GetSet {
    public function __call(){ /* does some magic */
}

trait RepositoryAware {
    public function getRepository(string $name)
    {
        /* makes use of the GetSetTrait*/
    }
}

class Controller
{
    use GetSet;
    use RepositoryAware;
}
```

Given the limitations of PHP, I can not simply put a `use GetSet` on the `RepositoryAware` trait because other traits that the controller imports could also bring the `GetSet` trait. Furhtermore, the controller class itself could be using the behavior provided by the `GetSet` trait.

Comment: Could i get some type of communication a bit more useful than a down vote ?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but I would REALLY like to hear it from the down voter what I might be doing wrong

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this in PHPUnit short of creating a new class that uses the traits ([at runtime if necessary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)) and mocking that. You don't say much about your actual situation, but if you're creating mocks then presumably your system-under-test is actually a different class? In that case you should be mocking its dependencies, which will be concrete classes (or interfaces). In short, why do you need this?

Comment: that is what i thought. I want to test a trait that adds a behavior to be able to fetch model classes as an alternative to passing the model classes in the constructor. This trait makes use of a GetSetTrait to call properties set by the first trait. I'll add the solution I have thus far as an answer but would love to hear any other suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution I have is to create a Dummy Class that imports both traits and mock that class instead:

```
class RepositoryAwareClass
{
    use GetSet;
    use RepositoryAware;
}
```

Like this I am able to properly test the behavior provided by the `RepositoryAware` trait while at the same time composing its requirement of the `GetSet` trait.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but it sounds like you want to add functionality to your class on the fly? There is a pattern for this called Decorator Pattern - maybe that is the way to go instead of all these Traits...

Comment: The functionality is not on the fly. I want my controllers to have the functionality of being able to lazy load repositories ( model objects) while at the same time, not have to inject all my repositories into my controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking concept was built with the idea that you would be using dependency injection. I can certainly see why you may not want to use dependency injection with this multiple inheritance like model that php uses called "Traits". Mocking tools like the one built for phpunit was built to substitute instances of objects not classes/interfaces/traits themselves. PHP Traits are more like having a static dependency instead of a dependency on an instance of an object. However, even if you were using traits and assuming a trait was basically the same as a class, according to mocking best practices should test the trait as its own test instead of testing a trait through another class. If you want to mock the trait itself you may want to try to revisit your design as I do not believe it can be done. You can certainly mock a trait and test that trait but you cannot mock a trait and then inject it as a dependency on an object. Imagine that a class for example implements an interface, mocking a trait would be the same a mocking an interface that a class implements, its not possible. You can only mock an interface of an object that a class depends upon through setter or constructor based dependency injection. Another example would be to try and mock the class that the class under test inherits from. You can't do that either. Perhaps in the javascript world this type of thing could be useful and from some people's point of view desired, but I think if you want to use mocking you would need to stick with `object` dependency injection instead of static `use` of traits.

So what's the alternative? I think the following example would be how to use perhaps "traditional" OOP practices with mocking to achieve your goal of sharing functionality without using inheritance. The example also makes your dependencies more explicit. And for the record, I applaud you for NOT using inheritance.

```
<?php

interface GetterSetter {
    public function __call();
}

interface RepositoryProvider {
    public function getRepository(string $name);
}

class GetSet implements GetterSetter {

    public function __call() {
        /* does some magic */
    }
}

class DefaultRepository implements RepositoryProvider, GetterSetter {

    /**
     * @var GetterSetter
     */
    private $_getterSetter;

    public function __construct(GetterSetter $getterSetter) {
        $this->_getterSetter = $getterSetter;
    }

    public function getRepository(string $name) {
        // makes use of the GetSetTrait
        $this->__call();
    }

    public function __call() {
        // makes use of the GetSetTrait
        $this->_getterSetter->__call();
    }
}

class Controller implements RepositoryProvider, GetterSetter {

    /**
     * @var RepositoryProvider
     */
    private $repositoryProvider;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->repositoryProvider = new DefaultRepository(new GetSet());
    }

    public function getRepository(string $name) {
        return $this->repositoryProvider->getRepository($name);
    }

    public function __call() {
        $this->repositoryProvider->__call();
    }
}
```

In general I feel like the PHP community took a wild left turn, trying to be more like javascript and I feel that traits can walk you into a corner. This is a very good example of such a corner. I would really avoid them, at least for now. In the long run I believe Generics would be the better solution to your problem of needing a generic GetSet piece of code but generics haven't been implemented in php yet :-(.